# Where to put tor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

When installing Tor Browser on Ubuntu 14.04 where do I put the installation folder when complete (it's in the downloads folder right now).

Comment: if you don't really know what to do with Tor and/or TBB i strongly advise you to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/)!

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in any directory and extract it there. You can even extract it in the Downloads directory. After extracting, you just need to execute the start-tor-browser script by running it in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the first answer, Tor is self-contained - it isn't "installed" in the way a normal Deb/Ubuntu package is, nor does it have to be built from source.

In short: put it anywhere you like, or follow the convention you've used for other standalone applications. (Mine's in my `home` directory.)